# Tcl - Free up memory in the middle of procedure

Tags: memory, tcl

We have a web application which is running on AOLServer. One of the features we provide requires the application to process large amount of data which is stored in several ns_sets. The process includes five steps. What we noticed is that the memory usage goes towards the limit after the first 3 steps and it goes out of memory in step 4. I have tried to use "unset" to free up the ns_sets used in step 1-3 without any success. So my question is how to properly free up those ns_sets used in those 3 steps and then step 4 and 5 can run through with adequate available memory?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code. ns_sets were a new thing to me so I searched for information on them. There seems to be API call `ns_set free setId`. Was that what you were using or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ns_set free` as noted in one of the comments above, see here for documentation:

http://panoptic.com/wiki/aolserver/Ns_set

You might want to consider using external storage such as the file system or a database. If you happen to be using the request thread to do the processing, you should consider using `ns_thread` or `ns_schedule_proc -thread` to execute each step. When a thread is finished (joined if using `ns_thread`) any `ns_set` created by the thread should be freed.